# Cyclic Interference Error with Nested Lambdas

Tags: java, playframework

I am attempting to create a registration handler for my Play Framework application but I am running into some trouble. The goal of this code is to grab the data that was submitted and then check if the username or email is in use. This is done using methods built into my User class, which is a model.

The register method:

```
public static F.Promise<Result> register() {
    // Get the POST data and turn it into something we can read from
    DynamicForm form = Form.form().bindFromRequest();

    // Get the email, username, and password
    String email = form.get("email");
    String username = form.get("username");
    String password = form.get("password");

    return User.findByUsername(username).map(user -> {
        // For .map to run we must not have encountered an error, this means
        // a user already has this username (otherwise the doc would not exist)
        return redirect("/register");
    }).recover(userCheckError -> {
        // For .recover to run there must have been an error. This will happen
        // if a doc was not found with the username (therefore it is not in use)
        return User.findByEmail(email).map(option -> { // ERROR START
            // We now have an F.Option object. If the email is already taken,
            // then the Option is defined (has a value within it), if the email
            // is free, the Option will be undefined (no value within it)
            if (option.isDefined()) {
                return redirect("/register");
            } else {
                return redirect("/register");
            }
        }); // ERROR END
    });
}
```

The findByUsername and findByEmail methods (in the User class):

```
public static F.Promise<User> findByUsername(String username) {
    return bucket.get(username.toLowerCase(), User.class);
}

public static F.Promise<F.Option<User>> findByEmail(String email) {
    return bucket.find("users", "by_email", QueryHelper.findOne(email), User.class).map(result ->{
        if (result.isEmpty()) {
            return F.Option.None();
        } else {
            User user = result.iterator().next();
            return F.Option.Some(user);
        }
    });
}
```

Edit: I have added comments to the register method and removed some unneeded code. I have also labeled where the error starts and ends (the lines that IntelliJ is highlighting. The exact error is "bad return type in lambda expression". The register method needs to return a `Promise<Result>` but that block of code is returning a `Promise<B>` (generic?).

### Javadocs:

http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/api/java/play/libs/F.Promise.html
http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/api/java/play/libs/F.Option.html

Comment: Could you post the **exact** error message?  Cut and paste all of it please.  And if you could produce an example that is complete it would help.  There's a lot of undefined variables and classes here.

Comment: Added the full error message and clarified some stuff. I can't really post all of the code for this as it's very specific to Play! Framework. I can however provide the Javadocs for the F.Promise and F.Option classes.